# Find python exe path on another drive

Tags: python, windows, exe

Hi I'm trying to find any python exe's on a drive other than my C drive.

I've written a python script that runs off my A: drive. However when I change my drive and run python, it uses the python exe from my C: drive.

```
H:\>A:
H:\>python
...
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

But I want to find out where on my A drive any python exes are installed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need python in another drive to run a script.

Just run `python PATH_TO_SCRIPT`

ie: `python A:\some_folder\myscript.py`

Or if you need other python, just point to the executable:

```
A:\python\python.exe A:\some_folder\myscript.py
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't know where on my A: drive python is intalled (there is a lot of stuff).

Comment: I know I don't need python on another drive to run my python script. I'm trying to centralise which version on python we all use as people have different versions).